# UIDatePicker min/max date

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, datepicker, uikit

I've created a UIDatePicker so that a user can select their birthday and I've tried to set the minimum and maximum allowable dates. However, setting the min/max dates like I've done below merely grays out the dates that are out of bounds but you can still scroll to them. How do I prevent the datepicker from scrolling to these dates instead of just merely graying them out?

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setDay:1];
[comps setMonth:1];
[comps setYear:1914];
NSDate *minimumDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];

NSDateComponents *compsMax = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[compsMax setDay:31];
[compsMax setMonth:12];
[compsMax setYear:2013];
NSDate *maximumDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:compsMax];

birthdayPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 150, 500, 10)];
[birthdayPicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
[birthdayPicker setMinimumDate:minimumDate];
[birthdayPicker setMaximumDate:maximumDate];
[birthdayPicker reloadInputViews];
[self addSubview:birthdayPicker];
```

Comment: I had a same problem. I solved this problem  by sub-classing UIPickerView. So basically I wrote my own Date Picker. You probably have to write your own Date Picker class

Answer (score 1):

I'll admit, it's not the best, but give it a shot, maybe it can be improved:

In `viewDidLoad`

```
[birthdayPicker addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(pickerValueChanged:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Somewhere else in code

```
- (IBAction)pickerValueChanged:(id)sender {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIDatePicker *datePicker = (UIDatePicker *)sender;
        if ([datePicker.date compare:datePicker.maximumDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
            datePicker.date = datePicker.maximumDate;
        }
        else if ([datePicker.date compare:datePicker.minimumDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
            datePicker.date = datePicker.minimumDate;
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: This seems to sort of work. After implementing this method in my code, the datepicker will unfortunately still scroll to out-of-bound dates, but it will (within a second or 2) jump back to the valid min/max date. It's definitely better than what I had before, so thank you.

Comment: @user1855952 Yeah, I realize it's not the best :( but I'll see if I can't make it better, it might just be a matter of changing the control event to something other than `UIControlEventValueChanged`.