# UIDatePicker min and max doesn't get changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uidatepicker

I'm trying to show a simple date picker with max date is today and min is 100 years ago but it doesn't work at all and the date picker have no limits.

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetHeight([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds)-250, CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds), 250);

        UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

        datePicker.minimumDate = [AppConfiguration currentDateMinusXYears:100];
        datePicker.maximumDate = [NSDate date];

        [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [self.view addSubview:datePicker];

+ (NSDate *)currentDateMinusXYears:(NSInteger)xYears
{    
    NSDate *today = [NSDate new];
    NSDateComponents *addComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    addComponents.year = - xYears;
    return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:addComponents toDate:today options:0];
}
```

Any ideas why?

**Edit 1:**
I ended up using 3rd party code.

Comment: Have you tried outputting the two dates and seeing what they actually are?

Comment: min: 1915-01-11 11:51:58 +0000, max: 2015-01-11 12:12:38 +0000

Comment: Is your issue similar to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024792/uidatepicker-constraints-not-working-in-device

Comment: Yes but I don't want to lock the choice of future dates, I don't want to see them at all.

Comment: As explained in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539575/uidatepicker-min-max-date), that's unfortunately not possible unless you subclass the UIDatePicker yourself. Standard behaviour is to grey out the "unavailable" dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setYear:30];
NSDate *maxDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];
[comps setYear:0];
NSDate *minDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];

[actionSheetPicker setMaximumDate:maxDate];
[actionSheetPicker setMinimumDate:minDate];
```

Comment: UIActionSheet Delegate and Datasource are set ?